# Office 365 EWS - GetUserAvailability ID is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

I am connecting to Exchange on 365 using EWS and using the GetUserAvailability method on the ExchangeService object to retrieve a collection of calendar items for a number of users (no more that 30).

My user that I am using to connect to EWS has impersonation rights and everything is working with the exception of one thing.

When I loop through the AttendeesAvailability collection, and then through each CalendarEvent within its CalendarEvents collection, I am able to see the Details object and access things like the Subject, Location, IsPrivate, etc...

The problem I have, is that the Details.StoreId is always null.

I have two 365 Exchange environments, our and a client's.  When I try and access the StoreId on ours, it works absolutely fine and has the unique ID as expected.  When I run the same come on the client's instance, it is null; but all the other properties are populated for the Details object.

This lead me to believe that it was a permissions issue for the service user within Exchange. So, I have slowly raised the permissions levels, hoping to hit the sweet spot, but nothing.  The user is now an Exchange Admin (which I believe should have blanket access to anything and everything within the Exchange environment - including calendar items for each person's mailbox).  Still not joy.

So, is it a configuration issue with the Exchange setup?

It is worth noting that all the other functionality that my application has, works perfect.  It is just this ID that I am missing.

I am at a loss on this one. If it wasn't for the fact that I have shaved my head due to the lock down, I would be pulling my hair out right about now.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

### UPDATE 1

So, I have found that if I perform the same process on the service account that I am authenticating with, I get the StoreId back.  This account was created after the migration from on-prem to O365 (which may mean nothing). I am in the process of getting access to another account that has been created since the migration to see if it works for that one as well.  This will help me identify if the issue is likely to be with the migrated mailboxes only or with any mailbox apart from the account used to authenticate. I will update soon...

### UPDATE 2

I have tested against a new account.  I set the default permissions on the new account's calendar to Reviewer (even tried Owner and Anonymous just for a sanity check).  When I authenticate using the service account, I don't get the StoreId.  When I authenticate using the new test account, I do get the StoreId.

This leads me to believe that it is a permissions issue. It's now a case of finding out what that magic permissions is. It still eludes me as to why it is only the ID that I don't get back.

Still open to any suggestions.

### UPDATE 3

It looks like it may be something different between build versions on EWS.

The version that works is reporting a server version of 15.20.3021.030.
The version that does not work is version 15.20.3045.019.

Comment: I am seeing this issue with any user that has no reviewer rights granted to the service account. Give the permission and StoreID appears. I'm on original Exchange 2106, no mogration, but I do not believe this to be the source of the issue.

Comment: could you find a fix for this problem? I've started to see this in an existing installation which used to work just fine few days/weeks ago. Was there an office365  change/update which deprecated this feature ? In Update 2 , you said that creating a new account solved this ? Can you please elaborate what type of account is it ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @adhiman, Adding a new account did not solve the issue.  What it did do thought was highlight that the issue was with obtaining the data from a calendar for a user other than the one that was used to authenticate. My service account can see IDs for its own calendar items, but not for the test account, and the test account can see IDs for its own calendar items, but not for the service account.  The ID is the only piece of data that is missing. Everything else is present as expected.

Comment: Hi @CarlHowarth, that's indeed the case. I'm able to retrieve event details (also StoreId) as long as I'm using its own account but using service account gives null for StoreId. Interesting finding about EWS build version update. Will be interesting to see release notes for this update.

Answer (score 1):

So, it's been a while, but Microsoft have now fixed the issue and the existing code is now working fine.

I can also confirm that this work when using OAuth as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably related to not having sufficient rights from the account you use for the Exchange Service authentication to the target account.
Use the command below to give rights and try again.

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity User@domain.com:\Calendar -User serviceceaccount@domain.com -AccessRights Reviewer
```

This is a very annoying issue, I have opened an incident with MS in the past, but got the disappointing answer that this won't change soon.

Below is the PS code to set rights to all users, rooms, resources, regardless of culture (language) and name of the calendar folder.

```
Param(
     [parameter(position=0,Mandatory=$true)][string] $serviceaccount,
     [parameter(position=1,Mandatory=$true)][string] $mailboxtype
)

$acl = "Reviewer"

if ($mailboxtype -eq "All") {
    $mailboxes = Get-Mailbox | Where {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox" -or $_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox" -or $_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "EquipmentMailbox"} | Select -expand PrimarySmtpAddress | Select -expand Address | Where {$_ -NotLike "Administrator@*"}
}
elseif ($mailboxtype -eq "Users") {
    $mailboxes = Get-Mailbox | Where {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox"} | Select -expand PrimarySmtpAddress | Select -expand Address | Where {$_ -NotLike "Administrator@*"}
}
elseif ($mailboxtype -eq "Resources") {
    $mailboxes = Get-Mailbox | Where {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox" -or $_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "EquipmentMailbox"} | Select -expand PrimarySmtpAddress | Select -expand Address
}
else {
"Error specifying target mailbox type. Choose one of: 'All', 'Users' or 'Resources'.`n
'All' - UserMailbox, RoomMailbox, EquipmentMailbox.`n
'Users' - UserMailbox.`n
'Resources' - RoomMailbox, EquipmentMailbox."
}

foreach ($mbx in $mailboxes)
{
    $calName = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $mbx -FolderScope Calendar | Where-Object { $_.FolderType -eq 'Calendar'} | Select-Object Name, FolderId #-ErrorAction Stop
    #echo "${mbx}:\$($calName.Name)"
    Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ${mbx}:\$($calName.Name) -User $serviceaccount -AccessRights $acl | Select-Object Identity, FolderName, User, AccessRights
}
```

Save as PS script, call with two params: serviceaccount & mailboxtype

Comment: Another problem might be that in different languages the Calendar folder will have different name...
You can use something like this to get localized name:
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity user@domain.com -FolderScope Calendar | Where-Object { $_.FolderType -eq 'Calendar'} | Select-Object Name, FolderId

Comment: Hi Kiril,
Thanks for responding.  We have already set the permissions for the mailboxes to Reviewer.  We had to do this to populate the CalendarEvent.Detail object (before we did this, the object itself was null).  We do get a populated Details object and all the properties are populated, with the exception of the StoreId (which is the unique id for the calendar item).

Comment: Hi Kiril, With regard to the language idea. Would you be able to offer a little more detail on how I would go about this? I presume that is performed in PS. Is it just a case of connecting to EWS in the normal way and then running that command?  Is there something specific that I should be looking for?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kiril, I have checked the Calendar folder name as suggested with a mailbox that works, and the names match. The folder ids are obviously different.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a simple script for giving rights to all calendar folders without knowing their exact names.

Comment: Hi Kiril, Since I have also started seeing this problem recently, Do you know if this is being caused by any of the office 365 updates ? I haven't been able to fix this issue as all the permissions needed for a service account are in place. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I am currently on my 3rd support ticket with M$ at the moment. They are now swaying to the idea that it is not a development issue, but actually a product issue. The email tennis is slow but if I get an answer, I will get details and share. It is frustrating to say the least.

Comment: Hi @KirilStankov, I did try the script that you sent on a specific mailbox to see if it made any difference, but unfortunately not. The permissions that are set up feel like they are correct. With the GetUserAvailability call, you can't really go wrong. As long as each calendar has Reviewer set for the default policy, and you request the detailed data in the call, all should just work.

Comment: I am working against Exchange 2016, not o365. In any case, for me the ID appears after giving the Reviewer rights. I was also on a support case with MS and got final answer that this behavior is by design... So I have my own workaround, which is pretty stupid, but once I get the item, I check the start time and the subject and then look for it in the folder, bind to it and retrieve the id. It is slow, but works, depends what your needs are.